# Remove/Hide columns in asp:repeater in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET repeater control that I would like to hide certain columns depending on the status of another variable.

Here is the repeater code along with the code-behind.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptAnimalPatients">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OwnerFirstName") %></td>
      <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OwnerLastName") %></td>
      <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AnimalID") %></td>
      <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status") %></td>
    </tr>        
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

private void LoadRecentlyCompletedReviews()
{
  var animalList = patientRepository.GetAnimals().ToList();

  rptAnimalPatients.DataSource = animalList;
  rptAnimalPatients.DataBind();
}
```

How would I go about hiding/removing certain columns based upon data retrieved at run-time? For example suppose that this list of animals was from an animal shelters where there were no owners. I would like to hide/remove the `OwnerFirstName` and `OwnerLastName` columns. Yet if the list was for a list of animals from a regular family vet I would like to display those columns. Just not sure how to remove certain columns programmatically from the code behind.

Answer (score 2):

Set Id in html code for td `<td id="tdOwner" runat="server">`

before bind set:

```
rptAnimalPatients.ItemDataBound += rptAnimalPatients_ItemDataBound;
```

and next:

```
void rptAnimalPatients_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{    
    if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        return;
    var tdOwner= (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("tdOwner");
    tdOwner.Visible=//make code to true or false
}
```